# After copying in Excel, can't copy anything outside of Excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, copy-paste, clipboard, microsoft-excel-365

I'm experiencing a frustrating issue with copying and pasting with Excel. I haven't been able to word it exactly so I haven't found much online except for an old "Keep Copy" function.

When I copy something in Excel and paste it into another program (such as SSMS), I am unable to copy anything outside of Excel until I go back into Excel and press ESC to get rid of the marquee. The biggest frustration for me is when I'm going between Excel and SSMS, moving a lot of data around, I can't copy any of my query results because of this issue.

I'm currently on Excel 365 (version 1808 build 10730.20280) on Windows 10 (version 1703 build 15063.1563). This is a work computer so updates are controlled by group policy. However all of my coworkers are on the same Excel version and are not having this issue and I've only started experiencing this a few weeks ago.

Comment: I think you should add info on your Windows version and tags to match, to try to get the right eyeballs on this question.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have added the Windows version and more tags.

Comment: Am too having the same issue, but in Netbeans application.
Using Windows 10 PRO 64bit